# Is there a way to add a class to an element followed by a character?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I have some HTML that looks like this:

```html
<p>
  <span class="word">keyword</span>
  ()
  <span class="word">another keyword</span>
</p>
```

How would I add a class using JavaScript (no jQuery) to any element with a class of "word" that has a "(" character directly after itself?
The HTML should look like this:

```html
<p>
  <span class="word parenthesis">keyword</span>
  ()
  <span class="word">another keyword</span>
</p>
```

Comment: How would I do that?

Comment: Can you show us what you have tried and we can help see what the issue is? StackOverflow is not a code writing service

Comment: You could query all elements with class `word` and check each next element

Comment: @jabaa The string is not in the next element, it's in a text node.

Comment: @Barmar I meant "next node" but wrote "next element"

Comment: Use [`.nextSibling`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/nextSibling) to get the next node after the element. Strip the leading whitespace, and check if the first character is `(`. Then add the class.

Comment: @Barmar This worked, added answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Using @Barmar's comment, I managed to write this:

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.word').forEach((el) => {
  if (el.nextSibling.data.trim().charAt(0) === '(') {
    el.classList.add('parenthesis');
  }
});
```

Answer (score -1):

```js
let classList = document.querySelectorAll('.word');

for (let i = 0; i < classList.length; i++) {
  classList[i].classList.add("anotherClass");

  //classList[i].classList.remove("word");
}
```

```css
.anotherClass {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<p>
  <span class="word">keyword</span>
  <span class="">-No class-</span>
  <span class="word">keyword</span>
  <span class="word">another keyword</span>
  <span class="word">keyword</span>
  <span class="">-No class-</span>
  <span class="word">keyword</span>
  <span class="word">another keyword</span>
</p>
```

Comment: Where does this check if the text node after the element begins with `(`?